# Hidden value in a Sencha Touch view

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I am working in a Sencha Touch app, from a Json file I am getting the customization of the cart icon with the next api.

```
{
  "user":
    {
      "orderEnabled": true
    }
}
```

Controller calls to the backend correctly but in the view I have a doubt with the hidden parameter in the component, How to set correctly the value of hidden sent from the backend?

For example:

```
          {
                title: 'Cart,
                iconCls: 'shoppingcart',
                itemId: 'cart',
                hidden: ' What should it be the value? backend send me the value'
            },
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

To hide the 'cart' component:

```
    {
        title: 'Cart,
        iconCls: 'shoppingcart',
        itemId: 'cart',
        hidden: true
   },
```

To show the 'cart' component:

```
    {
        title: 'Cart,
        iconCls: 'shoppingcart',
        itemId: 'cart',
        hidden: false
    },
```

If you are showing/hiding the component based on the value of a variable, then from within a controller you can retrieve the component using a [ComponentQuery](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery) and call .setHidden(true) or .setHidden(false) on it (assuming 'cart' supports the [hidden](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-hidden) config property).